# What are the ssh login attempts without user value in auth.log

Tags: logs, authentication, sshd

My auth.log to contains these two kinds of entries for ssh:
These

`Jun 27 07:28:25 myhost sshd[26898]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=some.ip.address.123  user=git`

and these

`Jun 20 21:46:18 myhost sshd[13881]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=some.ip.address.234`

As you can see the second kind does not include a "user=" field. Otherwise they have the same format. What does that mean? Is it possible to attempt ssh login without a username?

Comment: You can go for ssh login without specifing username if the machine on which you are trying to ssh has the same username as your local machine.

Comment: But shouldn't ruser be set in this case? Where can I find a description of the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines without ruser are written if the provided user is invalid on your system (try with `ssh whateverthereisnot@localhost`).

Unknown usernames are usually not recorded in logs because these might be usernames for a different system (accidental login attempt to the wrong machine), or worse, passwords (accidentally typed in the username field).

Comment: Wait, what is ruser and what is user?